# appended html to the dom doesn't respect the charset

Tags: javascript, html, character-encoding

I have some HTML rendered by ajax, which works perfectly fine using the char-set `utf-8` nevertheless some content it's appended to the dom by a JavaScript function using jquery. The problem is, the HTML rendered doesn't have the correct char-set.

Here's the example of the content added by JavaScript

```
var html = '<div class="right-item-container"><a href="#"><span style="font-size:24px;" class="item-friend-name">Mamá</span></a><br/><a href="#"><span class="clubName-container">school</span></a></div>';

$('.profile-container').empty().css({ 'padding-top' : '0'}).html(html);
```

It renders like this:

[image: html render]

[image]

Comment: Is this javascipt in an external file, and is that file saved as UFT8

Comment: you can usually over-ride the mime type (xhr.overrideMimeType) and specify a charset after the mime. ex: "text/html; charset=utf-8"

Comment: @adeneo That what's happens... thanks put your comment as a answer for me to mark as a accepted

Comment: That's ok, mark_huffington sort of has the right answer below, so just accept that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine in a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/HjCpp/

```
var html = '<div class="right-item-container"><a href="#"><span style="font-size:24px;" class="item-friend-name">Mamá</span></a><br/><a href="#"><span class="clubName-container">school</span></a></div>';


$('#test').html(html);
```

So it must be the way your original content is encoded.